# How to write a overriding method which returns the instace of the calling class in Java

Tags: java, builder, builder-pattern

I am relatively new to Java and Design patterns. I am trying to implement the Builder pattern for my application. I have an `interface` which has a method `build` this `build` method will take the class as a parameter and return the same.

```
public interface TestInterface {
    public TestInterface withTest(int start);
    public <T> T build();
}
```

As of now, I have implemented this `interface` within a single class and overriding the methods in the `GenerateBuilder` class and it works fine

```
public class GenerateNumbers {

private String start;

private GenerateGSRN(GenerateBuilder builder) {
        this.start = builder.start;
    }

    public static class GenerateBuilder implements TestInterface {

        private String start;

        @Override
        public TestInterface withGcp(String start) {
            this.start = start;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public GenerateNumbers build() {
            return new GenerateNumbers(this);
        }

    }
}
```

But I want to move the `GenerateBuilder` class which is overriding the methods to its own separate class so that it can be used by any other class (make it as common so I do not have to write this code again).

But as we can see the `GenerateBuilder` `Build` function is tightly coupled to `GenerateNumbers` due to which I am unable to move it. I want to change the `Build` method in `Interface` as well as during the `overriding` so that it will return the instance of the class to calling class.

For example: If `GenerateNumbers` is calling build method then `build` method should return `GenerateNumbers`. If `GenerateNumbersRandom` is calling then `build` method should return instance of `GenerateNumbersRandom`.

I tried couple of things but did not work:

In interface:
`public <T> T build(Class clazz);`

In the override:

```
@Override
        public <T> T build(Class clazz) {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        }
```

I hope I was able to explain the problem properly. Can someone please suggest me how to make this work.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want an instance of a children class to build another instance of the same class by calling a parent's _eventually `final`_ method?

Comment: Yes, I want the `build` method to return an instance of a child class that is making a call to it. For example in this case, when `GenerateNumbers ` makes a call it should create `GenerateNumbers ` similar to the way I have it now in hard coded value.

Comment: My main question would be: Why? You want a generic class that can create a generic builder object, which in its turns can generate another generic object. Why do you think you need all this complexity? What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have multiple classes that are similar to `GenerateNumbers` but produce different outputs. If I do not create a Generic class then I would end up writing the same code in each and every class but with a different class name. Hence, I would like to create a generic class so that I can use it in all classes and do not have to create this class within all the classes I create.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you could:

- declare your interface has having generic type (`Builder`)
- declare the type you want to be built by the class implementing the interface (`NumberGenerator`)
- declare the builder as an implementation of the interface having for generic type the class it will build (`NumberGeneratorBuilder implements Builder<NumberGenerator>`)
- in the `Builder` interface, access to *actual* type of generic at runtime to instantiate a new instance of this type.

---

As an example, this would give something like:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public interface Builder<T> {

  default T build() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    // in a more production-ready application, you would not reference item with their index but lookup through correct criterion to avoid getting a bad class instantiated
    return ((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).newInstance();
  }
}
```

```java
public class NumberGenerator {

  public static NumberGenerator instance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return new NumberGeneratorBuilder().build();
  }

  // Note that visibility is important here, default constructor needs to be visible from the Builder class, and not from its implementation
  NumberGenerator() {

  }

  public static class NumberGeneratorBuilder implements Builder<NumberGenerator> {

  }

}
```

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time and answering. But I am actually looking for an answer where I have to just modify my `Build` method in `Interface` and in implementation. I do not want to make the changes to the whole interface as it has many other methods that return different forms of data. I just want to know how can the `Build` method take the input as Class and return the instance of the same class to calling class.

Comment: So you can not add a generic type to your `TestInterface`?

Comment: Actually, I would not like to make any modifications to `Interface` itself as it has many methods and it has been implemented by many classes. I would like to just make a modification to my `build` method within it and also to the `build` method which has been overridden within the implemented classes.